# python is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python

I realize that a lot of people have had this question but I've tried their solutions and they haven't helped me.  I watched this video here but his solutions is not helping me:
[fix problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4yJi-cpwWk)

I can get python to work on the python app and using it the path of the python interpreter is

```
import sys
print (sys.executable)
>>> C:\Users\Owners\Documents\Python
```

I then set the environment variable like so:

[image: set environment variable]

I've also tried attached 'python.exe' but that didn't work either.  When I then write python in the terminal I get the error message in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a new environment variable in your system variables named `PATH` if it doesn't already exist then you need to add your python interpreter path to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Python.exe` file in Path won't work as it is just an executable file, also which version of Python have you installed because according to [this](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) python 3.9.0 and above won't run on Windows 7 or earlier.If this is not applicable in your case then click on New in your system variables menu and add `PATH` as name and locate the Python Application Path and Python Scripts Path in folders (i.e where you installed Python) and add it to the newly created `PATH`